# Full heap memory causes slow server - enable garbage collection? (Closed)

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection

I have a web server with nginx, apache and tomcat7.
On this server runs a java program.
I have also access to the server with putty.

Usually once a day the heap memory on the server is full (CMS Old Gen - Heap Memory on 100%) and the program is getting really slow. Then I login on the server and restart the tomcat7 service. The heap memory is cleared and the program runs properly again.

So I have two questions.

1. Do I have to run the garbage collection from the program or the server?
2. When the garbage collection is on the server, how do I enable it?

I don't know if this is enough information for you. If you need anything let me know.

Kind regards

Edit:

```
Memory Pool     Type         Maximum
CMS Old Gen     Heap Memory  316.81 MB
Eden Space      Heap Memory  66.56 MB
Survivor Space  Heap Memory  8.31 MB
Total                        391.68 MB
```

So this is an extract from the Apache Manager (unfortunately I can't post any pictures yet). When the CMS Old Gen is on 100% the program begins to run really slow.
On the local version of the app I started the JVM Monitor to see if there is any leak. Apparently the garbage collector runs properly there but not on the server.

Any suggestions?

So I have increased the heap size and I am now trying to close the leaks.
Thank you so much for your help. See you =)

Comment: Run a heap dump and examine for leaks.

Comment: check your java programs for leaks it may be due to object are not getting null reference after their use

Comment: you should provide more information. what JVM flags are used, GC logs, java version, how much memory the system has/is in use. it also sounds like you know very little about administrating JVMs, maybe you should read up on the basics first.

Comment: yeah that is true. I don't know a lot about server and JVMs and so on.
I don't know which flags are used, or where I can find the GC logs. Even though is it quite hard to find the right spot to learn the basics. If you search for the JVM you find everything and nothing..

Comment: Less than 400 MB Heap? I may be spoiled nowadays but to me that seems to be pretty small. Can you increase the max heap size? Does the machine have spare memory?

Answer (score 2):

The garbage collector runs per default. If you want to make sure that it is running you can start the jvm with the -Xloggc:{file} option to get some debug information on its activities.

If you need to restart tomcat to clear up the heap you probably have a memory leak in your application, as the comments already point out.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I probably have a memory leak in the application. The big question is where and can I run the diagnostics on the server?
Now I have to find out, how to start the jvm...

Comment: The start script of tomcat starts the jvm. You can add jvm options in there.